# How to ensure that certain ID shows up only once in core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4.5

So far, this is what I tried:

```
+(NSManagedObject *) getObjectWithStringOfValue:(NSString *) Value fromTable:(NSString*) table withAttribut:(NSString *) AttributName
{
    NSManagedObject * buffer=nil;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        buffer=[self LookUpObjectWithAttributeValue:Value fromTable:table WithAttribut:AttributName];
        if (buffer == nil)
        {
            //CLog( @"gk boleh create");
            buffer=[self CreateNewObjectFromTable:table];
            [buffer setValue:Value forKey:AttributName];
            [BGMDCRManagedObjectContextThreadHandler commit];
            NSAssert([self LookUpObjectWithAttributeValue:Value fromTable:table WithAttribut:AttributName], @"Object must exist and must only be one");
        }
        else
        {
            //assert(!(buffer.isFault));
        }
    }


    return buffer;
}
```

Basically the @synchronized is necessary. It is possible that one thread see that there is no object create and another thread do the same thing and they both commit 2 objects instead.

However, this often cause deadlock.

In my implementation, every thread has their own moc. So [BGMDCRManagedObjectContextThreadHandler managedobjectcontext] will give moc to that thread. Every moc has the same parent, a main managedobject context created on the main thread.

The lock happen when executeFetchRequest inside LookUpObjectWithAttributeValue halt. On the other hand, the main thread also halt on @synchronized(self).

I wonder how to fix this?

Should I ensure that the main managedObjectContext not to be associated with main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rarely access core data directly. So there is only one line of code in the whole program that do excecuteFetchRequest, for example.

I do performBlockAndWait every time what a child do indirectly access the parent

```
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    saveSuccesfully = [moc save:&error];
    if (!saveSuccesfully) {
        CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);
    }
    else{
    }
}];

[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
    fetchedObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}];

    [moc performBlock:^{
        if (![moc save:&error])
        {
            CLog(@"Error in Saving %@", error);// handle error
        }
    }];
```

No deadlock again since then.